# Display table information based on login

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching for hours trying to figure this question out with no luck. I am sure it is an easy thing to do, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

In my database I have a table for members which contains a username and  password. In my second table I have rows for name, url and description.

When the user logs in, I want specific links to show based on their username. So if John logs in, he will get to see all links associated with his name and so on.

For the life, of me, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any help or links on where I can read up on doing something like this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show the database structure if you want help. Junction is an option Joining tables is simpler, but it depends on your structure.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will probably need to add a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to associate users to links. If users cannot share links, you can add a username (or however you identify a user) to your links table instead.

If you share your current structure in detail, we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but here is a possible solution:

When a user logs in:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $logged_in_users_id;
```

Then when displaying the links:

```
$query = "SELECT `url`, `name` FROM `links_table` WHERE `user` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    print "<a href='{$obj->link}'>{$obj->name}</a><br />";
}
```

Hope that helps.